# Which operations must be performed using the Geoprocessing API in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-pro-sdk

I want to migrate .NET application from arcobjects to Arc GIS Pro SDK.
As I understand some operations such as creating tables and feature classes, creating and modifying fields need to be performed using the Geoprocessing API in Arc GIS Pro SDK. 
Where can I find full list of such operations or more information about it?

Comment: Taking a guess based on some of the tasks you mentioned: You want to call GP TOOLS using the SDK. With the add-in you're making you'd call CreateTable, AddField or Calc Field or whatever appropriate GP tool. This "list" would be any of the tools you'd find in the toolbox. Its just a matter of calling them through the SDK.

Comment: I know how call gp tools using the ArcGIS Pro SDK. I need a list of operations that were available in ArcObjects but unavailable in Pro SDK.

Comment: Such a list does not exist. The only list will be what is currently in the ProSDK.

Answer (score 1):

For more information, if not the full list you asked for first, I recommend consulting [When Should You Use the ArcGIS Pro SDK?](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/05/04/when-should-you-use-the-arcgis-pro-sdk/)

> To help you get up to speed on the ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET, we have
>   posted an initial set of samples, an API Reference, and concept
>   documentation on GitHub (as part of the ArcGIS Pro SDK beta program).
>   Additional resources including concepts, guide, tutorials, samples,
>   and snippets will be posted on GitHub with the release of ArcGIS Pro
>   1.1.